# Python path finding

Tags: path-finding, python

Im making a dungeon crawler in python, and I want to make it so that a certain enemy (only 1) will chase you through the dungeon

the map is stored like this:
[
  ['0','0', '0'],
  ['0','0', '0']
]

in which the cord's for the enemy (and the player) is placed like this: [x, y]

how may I do this?

Comment: Presumably you considered using a standard pathfinding algorithm like A*, or a simpler variant like Dijkstra's or Breadth-First Search if your map is small? How have you tried applying your research thus far to your problem and where specifically did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what you want to achieve.
I would want to know more about whether this is CUI/GUI, how the player and the crawler are going to behave, what happens when they *do* meet, what the zeroes stand for (empty spaces?), how the map is being updated, is it 2-D or 3-D, what libraries are you using etc.

I can only assume you are looking for a logic to implement a path finding algorithm in 2-D space, that is, how should the "dungeon crawler" chase you.

With so little information, my answer will be vague as well.
How *I* would do it is to have a 2-D map of the "dungeon", like so:

```
[                             # assuming 5x5 grid
    [ 0  , 0, 0, 0  , 0 ],    # 'P' is where the player is
    [ 'P', 0, 0, 0  , 0 ],    # 'C' is where the crawler is
    [ 0  , 0, 0, 0  , 0 ],    # Now, call function "updateCrawler"
    [ 0  , 0, 0, 0  , 0 ],    # to chase the player,
    [ 0  , 0, 0, 'C', 0 ],    # Call "updatePlayer" to react to the crawler
]
```

This is assuming that the player and the crawler are the only ones in this dungeon.

I would save the positions of both of these to avoid calculating them every time.
And I would have 2 functions to update both things. For a player, like so:

```
def updatePlayer(map, player_position):
    # Get the input (Keyboard? Screen? Mouse?)
    map[<player y>][<player x>] = 0

    if input == <go left>:
        # move player left, update player position

    if input == <go right>:
        # move player right, update player position

    if input == <go up>:
        # move player up, update player position

    if input == <go down>:
        # move player down, update player position
    map[<player y>][<player x>] = 'P'
```

As for the crawler, a (very) simple way would look something like this:

```
def updateCrawler(map, crawler_position):
    map[<crawler y>][<crawler x>] = 0

    if <player is above crawler>:
        # move crawler up, update crawler position

    if <player is left of crawler>:
        # move crawler left, update crawler position

    if <player is right of crawler>:
        # move crawler right, update crawler position

    if <player is below crawler>:
        # move crawler down, update crawler position
    map[<crawler y>][<crawler x>] = 'C'
```

Again, this depends very much on what else is in the world. Are there walls? Are there other creatures for crawler to avoid? And so on.

Hopefully, this is a starting place. I would also update my answer as and when the question is improved.